# Import module has no attribute

Tags: python, import, module

I'm using Python since few days and I'm trying to learn as much as possible from it. I'm using Jupyter notebook as well. I made a python file `fibo.py` where I code a function `fib` and I saved it. In the same folder I try to import that module and use the function fib

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import fibo
result = fibo.fib(10)
```

but I get the following error message :

```
AttributeError: module 'fibo' has no attribute 'fib'
```

Could you please give me some suggestions where the problem should be? Thank you in advance.

Comment: sorry but you'll have to provide at least a pseudo code of your `fibo.py` but even then that might not be enough. There are different path issues that could lead to what you are experiencing

Comment: Try `from fibo import fib` [Call a function from another file in Python](//stackoverflow.com/a/20309470)

Comment: Please share the entire error message, as well as some more context for this.

Answer (score 0):

This is the code for fibo.py

```
# Fibonacci numbers module\n",
  def fib(n):    # write Fibonacci series up to n
  a, b = 0, 1
  while a < n:
  print(a, end=' ')
  a, b = b, a+b
  print()
```

The error I get is here:

```
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-1-73202afd3146> in <module>
      3 
      4 import fibo
----> 5 result = fibo.fib(10)

AttributeError: module 'fibo' has no attribute 'fib'
```

I tried also

```
from fibo import fib
```

And I get the following:

```
 ImportError                               Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-2-b2d78eaf1dcb> in <module>
      4 import fibo
      5 #result = fibo.fib(10)
----> 6 from fibo import fib

ImportError: cannot import name 'fib' from 'fibo' (C:\Users\my_folder\Documents\JupyterWork\fibo.py)
```

Comment: Sorry guys, I solved the problem finally. I was writing the function in Jupyter notebook and i was saving 'save as' giving the name 'fibo.py'. This is the wrong way to do that. This operation of writing the function should be done outside Jupyter (using VS code or ATOM or Notepad ++ or even simple notepad) and save it as 'fibo.py'. In this way everything works fine.

Answer (score -1):

Save the file as .py using any text editor other than jupyter notebook.
Because jupyter notebook file are stored in JSON format.